# Two usb wifi adapaters, only wlan0 appears, how to get wlan1?

Tags: debian, usb, wifi

I'm attempting to connect two wifi USB dongles to a debian system. One is to connect to a local lan, the other I plan to use in adhoc mode to connect to a specific device. You could look at this as an attempt to connect two wifi dongles to a linux device to connect to two separate wifi networks at the same time.

The USB devices appear to be recognised correctly with no problems. ifconfig reports wlan0 and I was able to setup /etc/network/interfaces so it configures correctly and connects to my lan via my access point.

My /etc/network/interfaces is:

```
auto wlan0

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface wlan0 inet dhcp

wpa-conf /etc/wpa.config
```

my /etc/wpa.config is:

```
ap_scan=1
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant

network={
    ssid="###"
    psk="##########"
}
```

Both usb wifi dongles are identical (ASUS EX N) and the first one is recognised and I can configure (as above), while the second one is detected but not recognised as a lan device. Experimenting with dmesg I can find out the following for each usb device:

dmesg | grep "usb1"

```
[    1.841842] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.850929] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.860403] usb usb1: Product: DWC OTG Controller
[    1.867357] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.2.27+ dwc_otg_hcd
[    1.875306] usb usb1: SerialNumber: bcm2708_usb
```

dmesg | grep "1-1:"

```
[    2.343158] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using dwc_otg
[    2.563416] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=9512
[    2.572622] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.583814] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.591025] hub 1-1:1.0: 3 ports detected
```

dmesg | grep "1-1.1:"

```
[    2.873414] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using dwc_otg
[    2.983730] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=ec00
[    2.995145] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    3.078641] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0: eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-bcm2708_usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:e8:9f:ac
[   24.257871] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0: eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xCDE1
```

dmesg | grep "1-1.2:"

```
[    3.193382] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
[    3.306387] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0b05, idProduct=1786
[    3.319133] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    3.329079] usb 1-1.2: Product: ASUS EZ N Network Adapter
[    3.340862] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Manufacturer Realtek 
[    3.349052] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
```

I've tried googling but cannot find any info about connecting two wifi dongles to a device. I suspect that I have to somehow apply the drivers (which are obviously already available) and make wlan1 appear, once there then I will be able to figure out the rest. Any help would be appreciated.

Added extra information as requested:

lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0b05:1786 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. USB-N10 802.11n Network Adapter [Realtek RTL8188SU]
```

/var/log/messages (sample, presuming this is relevant):

```
[   13.057545] r8712u: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   13.500489] r8712u: DriverVersion: v7_0.20100831
[   13.783452] r8712u: register rtl8712_netdev_ops to netdev_ops
[   13.791591] r8712u: USB_SPEED_HIGH with 4 endpoints
[   14.027050] r8712u: Boot from EFUSE: Autoload OK
[   15.017889] r8712u: CustomerID = 0x0010
[   15.024091] r8712u: MAC Address from efuse = 30:85:a9:6e:a6:bb
[   15.032267] r8712u: Loading firmware from "rtlwifi/rtl8712u.bin"
...
[   30.073530] r8712u: 1 RCR=0x153f00e
[   30.074269] r8712u: 2 RCR=0x553f00e
...
[   38.336980] r8712u: [r8712_got_addbareq_event_callback] mac = 58:6d:8f:00:37:45, seq = 0, tid = 0
```

The mac addy 30:85:a9:6e:a6:bb matches the one from ifconfig, so I am presuming that the r8712u is what is used for the ASUS EX N that is recognised. `ifconfig -a`:

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:e8:9f:ac  
      inet addr:192.168.1.132  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:656 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:453 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:59529 (58.1 KiB)  TX bytes:105486 (103.0 KiB)

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:85:a9:6e:a6:bb  
      inet addr:192.168.1.117  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:418 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:111070 (108.4 KiB)  TX bytes:1308 (1.2 KiB)
```

Please note that while I'm an experienced Unix/Linux user, I'm not very experienced with the kernel and drivers. So please be patient with me.

More info:

Tried replacing the second wifi dongle with a flash drive. That worked fine. Looking at messages I can see that it detects a usb 1-1.3, which it doesn't detect if I have the second wifi dongle in there.

```
[    9.443324] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[    9.945760] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=1000
[    9.963268] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    9.976352] usb 1-1.3: Product: USB DISK
[    9.982674] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: SMI Corporation
[    9.992819] scsi0 : usb-storage 1-1.3:1.0
```

Even more info:

I decided to switch the to move the wifi dongle that works to the other usb port and then decided to plug in the other one. Interestingly `lsusb` now states:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0b05:1786 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. USB-N10 802.11n Network Adapter [Realtek RTL8188SU]
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0b05:1786 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. USB-N10 802.11n Network Adapter [Realtek RTL8188SU]
```

So it appears to detect both now (no idea why this is different to before). Strangely though wlan1 isn't coming up automatically, not sure why. In `/var/log/messages` I now see:

```
[    3.173177] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
[    3.296059] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0b05, idProduct=1786
[    3.305833] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    3.320060] usb 1-1.2: Product: ASUS EZ N Network Adapter
[    3.331367] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Manufacturer Realtek
[    3.343032] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
[    3.443224] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[    3.566236] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0b05, idProduct=1786
[    3.575638] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    3.585429] usb 1-1.3: Product: ASUS EZ N Network Adapter
[    3.593239] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Manufacturer Realtek
[    3.601034] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
...
[   11.713221] r8712u: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   11.728515] r8712u: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   12.124771] r8712u: DriverVersion: v7_0.20100831
[   12.131967] r8712u: register rtl8712_netdev_ops to netdev_ops
[   12.550340] r8712u: USB_SPEED_HIGH with 4 endpoints
[   12.691051] r8712u: Boot from EFUSE: Autoload OK
[   13.716918] r8712u: CustomerID = 0x0010
[   13.723264] r8712u: MAC Address from efuse = 30:85:a9:6e:a6:c9
[   13.731529] r8712u: Loading firmware from "rtlwifi/rtl8712u.bin"
[   13.740279] r8712u: DriverVersion: v7_0.20100831
[   13.750556] r8712u: register rtl8712_netdev_ops to netdev_ops
[   13.760178] r8712u: USB_SPEED_HIGH with 4 endpoints
[   13.774319] r8712u: Boot from EFUSE: Autoload OK
[   14.532517] r8712u: CustomerID = 0x0010
[   14.538717] r8712u: MAC Address from efuse = 30:85:a9:6e:a6:bb
[   14.546902] r8712u: Loading firmware from "rtlwifi/rtl8712u.bin"
...
[   32.273631] r8712u: 1 RCR=0x153f00e
[   32.274494] r8712u: 2 RCR=0x553f00e
```

Via `ifconfig` I am only seeing wlan1 and not wlan0. Very weird...

---

Changed `ifconfig` to `ifconfig -a` above, output is the same (wlan1 is not shown). If I do a `ifconfig wlan1` then I get:

```
wlan1: error fetching interface information: Device not found
```

When I swap them around and `lsusb` is showing all five usb devices (listed above), when I do a `ifconfig -a` I get both wlan0 and wlan1:

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:e8:9f:ac  
      inet addr:192.168.1.132  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:117 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:95 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:12685 (12.3 KiB)  TX bytes:12594 (12.2 KiB)

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:85:a9:6e:a6:bb  
      inet addr:192.168.1.117  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:32 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:5674 (5.5 KiB)  TX bytes:1098 (1.0 KiB)

wlan1 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:85:a9:6e:a6:c9  
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

and doing a `ifconfig wlan1` shows the wlan1 info as shown above.

---

`ip link show` in the swapped usb device config shows:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:e8:9f:ac brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 30:85:a9:6e:a6:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DORMANT qlen 1000
    link/ether 30:85:a9:6e:a6:bb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: You need to provide better information. You only show us dmesg output of one wlan device being recognized, not two. Does `/var/log/messages` contain any information? which driver is used for the wlan devices?

Comment: `lsusb` says...?

Comment: @user1129682 I am not familar with the logs or with the commands like lsusb and dmesg sorry. I've modified my post to include extra info from `/var/log/messages` that looked appropriate to me. Is there a service where I can post the logs and show here?

@IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I've added the lsusb, sorry forgot to add that the first time I posted.

Comment: just also check that manually running `ifconfig wlan1` gives an error... `ifconfig` will not normally show interfaces that are down... `ifconfig -a` will show them though...

Comment: Has Gert pointed out, you need to put `ifconfig -a` not just `ifconfig`. Or you use `ip link show`.

Comment: @GertvandenBerg with the usb devices plugged in as originally done, `ifconfig -a` is same as `ifconfig`, however if I swap the usb devices around, it changes. Posted changes above.
@user1129682 updated above. Btw guys, thanks for your help so far. I'm not familiar with this side of Linux and it looks like to me that there are some peculiarities with the hardware making it even more fun.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, looks like swapping the order of the usb dongles fixed the problem. It wasn't a debian configuration issue, looks like it's hardware. I've added an answer to this question, hope that's the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the device I'm using doesn't like the two wifi dongles connected in the order that I had them connected. Reversing the order in which they are connected resulted in both wifi dongles being recognised (as seen via `lsusb`) and then consequently configurable via `/etc/network/interfaces`, after which they could be brought up via `ifup wlan1`.

The final entries in `/etc/network/interfaces` that worked was:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa.config

auto wlan1
iface wlan1 inet dhcp
    wireless-essid ardrone_3
```

and the results with `ifconfig` are:

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:e8:9f:ac  
      inet addr:192.168.1.132  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:5111 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3001 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:431610 (421.4 KiB)  TX bytes:552794 (539.8 KiB)

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:85:a9:6e:a6:bb  
      inet addr:192.168.1.117  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:4743 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:1322366 (1.2 MiB)  TX bytes:1309 (1.2 KiB)

wlan1 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:85:a9:6e:a6:c9  
      inet addr:192.168.1.3  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:2420 (2.3 KiB)  TX bytes:1476 (1.4 KiB)
```

As can be seen, both wifi devices are working and have received ip addresses.

It appears that the problem was not a configuration issue of debian but an issue with the hardware that required the two devices to be swapped.

A big thank you to Gert van den Berg and user1129682 for their patience with me.

Comment: @user1129682 Answers should be posted as answers. It doesn't matter if the OP answers his own questions, it is even encouraged to do so on this website. See the FAQ.

Comment: Ignore user1129682; you're [supposed to post an answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) if you solve your own question. You can even accept it once the site will let you (you have to wait two days though)